# Django, the user model, profiles, and security

Tags: django, security, profile

I just started fidling with the user model, and I'm probably wrong on this but I just had a thought and I'm not knowledgable enough to persuade myself it is indeed wrong.

I have a user model, which I extended with a profile via a one-to-one model. (most sources I could find recommended this as a best practice).

Now, it is possible for general users on my app to access bits of the profile data, such as someone's username (part of the user model) or nationality (part of the profile model).

I grab this data in a view I created via objects.get and pass on the results to a template. But doesn't this also pass on the (hashed) passwords? And if so isn't this unsafe?

Answer (score 0):

No. Why would passing the user model to the template be unsafe? End users don't have control of the template, only your code does. If you don't use the password in the template anywhere, then the end user will not have access to it.

In any case, even if you did use it, as you point out only the hashed password is present; but a hash itself is useless. To log a user in, Django needs a raw password which hashes to the same value; but hashes are not easily reversible, which is the whole point of using them.